# after decrypting an encrypted pdf that had content, the result of the decryption is empty

Tags: node.js, pdf, encryption, cryptography

using the Node.js crypto library, I encrypted the PDF like so:

```
//encrypting the pdf
fs.readFile('./full.pdf', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', encPassword);
    var text = data;
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    console.log(crypted);
});
```

I then take `crypted` and run it through:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', encPassword);
var dec = decipher.update(args[0],'hex','utf8');
dec += decipher.final('utf8');                                            

fs.writeFileSync('./output.pdf', dec);
```

./output.pdf is now one blank page where it should be full with the original content.

**note**

When I use this same exact code (excluding `fs.writeFileSync('./output.pdf', dec);`) to encrypt and decrypt a simple string  it encrypts and decrypts flawlessly.

Comment: What do you have in `args[0]` before the `decipher.update` call?

Comment: Because the encryption and decryption are 2 separate scripts. To decrypt I take the output of the first one (`$crypted`) and use that as a command line argument in the decryption script

Comment: What if you try to put encode and decode steps in one script and pass it just through js variable?

Comment: Same result. Empty pdf

Comment: Could it not be an issue in the en/decryption but an issue in the writing to file?

Comment: What if you use plain text data *and* `fs.writeFileSync` the results?

Comment: I added `dec = "asdf";` right before the `fs.write...`  line (and changed `pdf` to `txt`) and it created a perfect little text file

Comment: BTW, are you sure about input encoding? You are using UTF-8, but it's PDF. Maybe you need `binary`?

Comment: `cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')` - this means that `text` uses `utf8` encoding. But PDF is binary format.

Comment: ok, so I changed all the `utf8`s to `binary`s and I'm still getting an empty pdf. Was that the fix you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the writing. The decryption `dec` output a string. That string had to be converted to a binary buffer and THAN written to a file.

Works like a charm now:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', encPassword);
var dec = decipher.update(args[0],'hex','binary');                               
dec += decipher.final('binary');       

var buffer = new Buffer(dec, "binary");                                          
fs.writeFileSync('./output.pdf', buffer);
```

Comment: So I was right ;) For me it works like this: `fs.writeFileSync('./output.pdf', dec, 'binary')`.

Comment: You were very helpful, but the issue wasn't the binary issue. It was that I wasn't writing a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-qpdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf) package to encrypt and decrypt PDFs. It makes use of [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/).